# Wrong data passed to component in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have 1 component nested two times in parent component

```
<day-selector [SelectedDate]="selectedDate" (onDayChange)="onDateChangebyChild($event)" ></day-selector>
<day-selector [SelectedDate]="selectedDate" (onDayChange)="onDateChangebyChild($event)" ></day-selector>
```

(both are the same)

and in day-selector.component.template.html I output the "SELECTED DATE"

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="SelectedDate" />
```

For some reason they print different data. Why is this happening?

Here's the DaySelector Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'day-selector',    
    templateUrl:'app/shared/day-selector/day-selector.component.html'

}) 

export class DaySelectorComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() SelectedDate: Date;
    @Output() onDayChange: EventEmitter<any>;

 constructor() {
        this.onDayChange = new EventEmitter();
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the data they printing? Does that data make sense? It would be helpful if you could provide a Plunker with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you convert `selectedDate` into `Date DataType` before sending to child component.